# how does nhibernate handle update collisions behind the scenes with the ver column?

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

I'm just looking for some documentation on how hibernate handles collisions using the ver column.

understanding thus far: 
a change to a row means that the changed row is inserted with a new version number

-- Is this done via "select max(ver)+1"? --

subsequently the previous version gets deleted.

btw: how do we know that {"select max(ver)+1"; insert} will be guaranteed to be an atomic operation?  Are they locking the row first?

Thanks in advance for any info.  I'm just trying to gain a complete understanding.

Comment: Are you talking about optimistic locking? if that's the case, hibernate updates the row with the next version, it doesn't insert new + delete old. Check how it works [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)

Comment: yep.  I want optimistic locking.  I'll check out the link .  Thanks.

Comment: @Augusto: that link doesn't have any info on hibernate. I understand optimistic locking, just I'm used to schemes implemented by the DBMS such as timestamps or ids of some kind. Does hibernate use these shemes, but only insert a new version if there's a clash?  My comment isn't clear because of my grok level right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll expand a bit more here. What hibernate executes for an update is something like

```
UPDATE table SET string = 'string', number = 1, version = version+1 
WHERE id = %Id% AND version = %Version%
```

This means that the update will only succeed if the version is still the same as when the object/row was loaded from the database and update the version number in the same query.

Comment: So we assume that mostly two processes will not try to update with the same version number, and if they do, one of them will fail?

Comment: @sgtz: ALL OF THEM except the first one will fail.

Answer (score 1):

See http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency